# VS 2015 update 3 breakpoint in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

After installing dotnetcore and update 3 my debugging been shot to hell. I can debug code but not global.asax - and I'm running iisexpress and it worked up until the update.

The thing is that it isn't all projects. Some of the simpler ones I can step into a breakpoint in global.asax. My colleagues are on update 2 and for them it is no problem with breakpoints in all of the projects.

I could live with the problem if it was only breakpoint problem, but it does not seem to load global.asax as it should, since my override of ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback for self signed cert does not  work for me but it does for my colleagues.

I did have a problem with any breakpoints until I delete all bin folders and obj folders, and deleted all temporary aspnet files under the windows dotnet folder.

I have gone through most of the post about settings for debug and projects, to no avail, and I've reinstalled vs 2015 two times. I can't find the download of vs 2015 professional update 2 on visualstudio.com...they only seem to have the latest and nothing else.

Anyone have any ideas?

/Erik

Comment: update: It seems to sometimes hit the break point in application_start when i go past the error for invalid cert, and call a get method via browser...but not always. When it hit the breakpoint my override for cert works as expected. Doesn't the vshost have to load global.asax when the project starts for it to return invalid cert error to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the weirdest fix ever. I think it is more of a workaround, though.

This was fixed by setting both default url to the folder(it was not the root folder) where I had my start page AND setting the page to default start page under project properties.

If I had set the start page, but not set the default url to the folder where the page was located it would not load global.asax when starting. And if I had only set the start page it would not find it - so I think there is a bug here somewhere.

/Erik